# Capturar excepciones sin que se cierre la aplicación

Tags: android, sqlite

Resulta que tengo un programa android, en donde quiero capturar la excepción que me diga:

> "La versión de la base de datos no es compatible con la versión de la
>   aplicación".

He intentado poner en el `AdapterDatabase` cuando abre la base de datos para escribir, que me muestre un mensaje determinado, pero cuando ocurre esa excepción directamente se sale de la aplicación. Quisiera que se quedará en la pantalla de Inicio y muestre ese mensaje.

[image: Excepción]

[image: Mensaje que quiero que salga en la pantalla de inicio de la aplicación]

El código sería el siguiente

```
public AdapterDatabase mAbrirBdParaEscritura()
    {
        try {
            myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(myContext, myNombreDb);
            myDb = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();    
        }
        catch (SQLException ex){
            ctiMetodos.mMostrarMensaje(myContext.getApplicationContext(),"Error","La versión de la base de datos no es compatible con la versión de la aplicación","Aceptar",false);
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

Y el método de mostrar mensaje sería este otro:

```
public void mMostrarMensaje(Context context, String sTituloMensaje, String sTextoMensaje, String sTextoBoton, boolean bCancelable)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        builder.setTitle(sTituloMensaje);
        builder.setMessage(sTextoMensaje);
        builder.setCancelable(bCancelable);

        builder.setPositiveButton(sTextoBoton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }
```

Comment: Puede que este no sea el problema, pero ¿puedes verificar que el import de SQLException sea "import android.database.SQLException" en lugar de "import java.sql.SQLException"?

Comment: Podrias pegar el codigo en lugar de usar una imagen? Es mas facil para que podamos copiarlo si es necesario para reproducirlo. Saludos!

Comment: El problema es la versión de la base de datos que generas, revisa tu clase DatabaseHelper que extiende de SQLiteOpenHelper , agregué una respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Este no es un error que deberías tratar de capturar en este punto ya que el problema es que la base de datos no puede ser leída.

Lo que debes realizar es revisar la clase que extiende de [SQLiteOpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper) en la cual se construye tu base de datos. Aquí se esta definiendo una versión 137, la cual es menor a la versión que esta instalada en tu dispositivo.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 137;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "basededatos.db";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

Puedes eliminar los datos de tu aplicación para que pueda funcionar, pero lo ideal es aumentar la versión para que se construya la nueva estructura de la base de datos, en este caso como la última es 139, debes cambiar a 140:

```
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 140;
```